# centos7 cannot stop mysqld

Tags: linux, mysql, centos-7

I am running **centOS 7** server on a VPS and trying to stop `mysqld`.
It is empty and nothing in it.
I am able stop it shortly, but after about 10 to 20 seconds, it is restarted automatically!

None of these ways **permanently** works!
I have root access.

```
# mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
# /bin/systemctl stop mysqld.service
# killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld
#
# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.63-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

and `/var/lib/mysql` error log

```
190520 20:46:06 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/server.shakiba.it.pid ended
190520 20:47:01 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
190520 20:47:01 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.63-MariaDB) starting as process 30381 ...
190520 20:47:01 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
190520 20:47:01 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
190520 20:47:01 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
190520 20:47:01 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
190520 20:47:01 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
190520 20:47:01 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
190520 20:47:01 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
190520 20:47:02  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
190520 20:47:03 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.61-MariaDB-38.13 started; log sequence number 2746956
190520 20:47:03 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
190520 20:47:03 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
190520 20:47:03 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
190520 20:47:03 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.63-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
```

Comment: After the `systemctl stop` you also need to do `systemctl disable` so it won't restart later.

Comment: @chicks. I tested. Did not work. It was came up again!

Answer (score 0):

Since I had `root` access on the Server (VPS) I did not think that **Direct-Admin** can reject the `root` command, but it did.

In **Service Monitor** section in DA, we can stop / start `mysqld`. That is it.